# Spring JPA + MySQL and deadlocks

Tags: java, mysql, spring, jpa, deadlock

I'm working on a REST API implemented in Java with Spring Boot. I used the embedded, in-memory database H2 for several weeks but at some point I've noticed something wrong with transaction isolation.

More precisely, I have a table where I need to track "duplicate" records. A duplicate is just a record which is equal to another for a well defined subset of the table's columns. So, basically, when I insert a new record I first check if it's a duplicate and mark it accordingly. A boolean column "duplicate" serves for this purpose.

For instance, let's say that B and C are the columns I check in order to define duplicates. This is a valid state:

`| A | B | C | duplicate |
| - | - | - | --------- |
| x | y | z |   false   |
| z | y | z |   true    |
| x | y | y |   false   |
| x | y | y |   true    |
| y | y | y |   true    |`

while this is *not* a valid state:

`| A | B | C | duplicate |
| - | - | - | --------- |
| x | y | z |   false   |
| z | y | z |   true    |
| x | y | y |   false   |
| x | y | y |   true    |
| y | y | y |   false   |`

...because row 3 and row 5 have the same values for both B and C, so one of the two has to be marked as duplicate.

In other words, my requirement is to mark as duplicate any row that happens to have already used values. Only one row for a given set of values will be allowed to have `duplicate == false`.

However, my Spring-based implementation was not working as expected. For instance, inserting 100 rows with the same values should result in 99 duplicates and only one non-duplicate. But when I tried to perform those inserts in parallel, a lot of duplicates were not detected.

I tried several fixes and at some point I started to think that H2 was not implementing the SERIALIZABLE isolation level correctly. I created a little app to demonstrate it:

```
@RestController
public class NewFooCtrl {

  @Autowired
  private FooRepo repo;

  @RequestMapping(value = "/foo", method = RequestMethod.POST)
  @Transactional(isolation = Isolation.SERIALIZABLE)
  public void newFoo(@RequestBody Foo foo) {
    List<Foo> foos = repo.findByBar(foo.getBar());
    if (foos.isEmpty()) foo.setDuplicate(false);
    else foo.setDuplicate(true);
    repo.save(foo);
  }

}
```

**Note:** I omit obvious code such as models and repositories. The `Foo` model has an identifier (type UUID) a `bar` property (type String) and a `duplicate` property (type boolean). Duplicate checking is based on the `bar` property.

With H2 I have a lot of missed duplicates (10% usually). With MySQL I always have correct results (i.e. the number of rows marked as duplicate is *exactly* N - 1 with N being the number of inserted rows). The only problem is that only a small fraction of the inserts succeed (from 1% to 30% at most).

I got a huge number of deadlock related exceptions. Why is that? How could such simple code cause a deadlock. I mean, it's a just a select followed by an insert.

Any suggestion?

Comment: What is the version of H2 and store engine are you using?

Comment: I don't know how to check it. I found some MySQL code to query the engine of a given table, but it seems not to be working on H2. As for the version, I list the dependency in my `pom.xml` without a version number, so maybe it's the latest (?).

Comment: please try to add to database url `LOCK_MODE=1;MVCC=TRUE;`

Comment: Ok, with those options I finally have correct results with H2 too. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the deadlock-related exceptions were caused by the way I was testing the demo app. More precisely, the test code was written in JavaScript / Node.js, which is *extremely* fast when it comes to start I/O tasks. All the transactions where requested almost simultaneously (and maybe automatically *retried* simultaneously?).

By adding a very short wait (e.g. 10 ms) between each request, I obtained a reasonable throughput and a very low number of deadlock-related exceptions.

My guess is that there is no deadlock at all. Just very high lock contention, which some sort of heuristic at the database level interprets as a possible deadlock. In fact, by disabling deadlock detection from the MySQL CLI I completely eliminated those deadlock-related exceptions (although they were replaced by lock wait timeouts).

Answer (score 2):

The application should not check for duplicate keys itself in a transaction. Leave this to the Database engine with a unique index, catch the Exception if it occurs, and try again with another identifier.

If you really want to solve this at the application level, maybe you should lock the table manually as soon as you open the transaction. The isolation level can do this automatically for you, but at a high performance cost (which you probably do not want).

Another solution would be optimistic locking, with the `@Version` annotation, but then you won't be able to guarantee the identifier uniqueness.

---

It is difficult to diagnose your deadlock issue, but it usually appears when you have recursive transactions (a transaction open in another transaction). Check your beans `@Scope`, they can create such issues. Also, make sure that you have only one `TransactionManager` and one `EntityManager` bean.

Comment: Hi Guillaume, thanks. Checking duplicates at the DB level is a reasonable option, but I prefer to keep the check at the application level. As for the deadlocks, my demo app is really simple and of course I don't have nested transactions or non-default (singleton) scope for my beans. My guess is that all those deadlock-related exceptions are just the result of some deadlock-detection heuristic but there is no actual deadlock.